# SoapClient LibXMLError: failed to load external entity, SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to establish a SOAP connection using the following PHP code, and it's failing at the point of the SoapClient construct:

```
// Need to declare these settings here because our php.ini has alternate
// settings due to global purposes for other PHP scripts
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache", "0");
ini_set("display_errors","On");
ini_set("track_errors","On");

// FedEx web services URL, note the HTTPS
$path_to_wsdl = 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com/web-services';

$soap_args = array(
    'exceptions'=>true,
    'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'trace'=>1)
;

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl,$soap_args);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump(libxml_get_last_error());
    echo "<BR><BR>";
    var_dump($e);
}
```

This outputs:

```
object(LibXMLError)#1 (6) {
    ["level"]=> int(1)
    ["code"]=> int(1549)
    ["column"]=> int(0)
    ["message"]=> string(71) "failed to load external entity "https://wsbeta.fedex.com/web-services" "
    ["file"]=> string(0) ""
    ["line"]=> int(0)
}

object(SoapFault)#2 (9) {
    ["message":protected]=> string(158) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com/web-services' : failed to load external entity "https://wsbeta.fedex.com/web-services" "
    ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) ""
    ["code":protected]=> int(0)
    ["file":protected]=> string(53) "/mnt/array/bell-enterprise/bell/fedex_shipservice.php"
    ["line":protected]=> int(34)
    ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> array(6) {
            ["file"]=> string(53) "/mnt/array/bell-enterprise/bell/fedex_shipservice.php"
            ["line"]=> int(34)
            ["function"]=> string(10) "SoapClient"
            ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient"
            ["type"]=> string(2) "->"
            ["args"]=> array(2) {
                [0]=> string(37) "https://wsbeta.fedex.com/web-services"
                [1]=> array(4) {
                    ["exceptions"]=> bool(true)
                    ["soap_version"]=> int(1)
                    ["cache_wsdl"]=> int(0)
                    ["trace"]=> int(1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL
    ["faultstring"]=> string(158) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com/web-services' : failed to load external entity "https://wsbeta.fedex.com/web-services" "
    ["faultcode"]=> string(4) "WSDL"
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After 6 hours of headache, the ONLY solution is to download the WSDL files.

https://wsbeta.fedex.com/web-services
and
https://ws.fedex.com/web-services

It will always throw an error 500, because this is not the wsdl.

Once you download the wsdls from *Technical Resources -> FedEx WebServices For Shipping -> GetStarted* (click on "Rate Services" and then "Download WSDL or XML"), in your script you will need to load your locally stored WSDL and everything will work like a charm.

```
$this->_soapClient = new SoapClient("RateService_v13.wsdl", array('exceptions'=>true, 'trace' => true));
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks Justin. This is what I eventually found out to be true myself, and as I read back over this original post, I never closed it out with the correct answer noted.  Yours is indeed the correct solution, which I find after hours of beating my head against the wall as well.  The FedEx documentation is horribly lacking in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

That url is NOT the path to a WSDL , but the url the SOAP requests should be going to. Never worked with the guys, but I gather you can get a wsdl file *somewhere* and store it locally, and you can alter the endpoint in that wsdl to the wsbeta one.  I cannot find the wsdl's and the fedex site doesn't allow me to go further in their dev technical resources without signing up, so I'll leave it at that: you *wsdl* is somewhere else, the url you have is just the location of a particular service.

Comment: Thanks Wrikken.  As noted on Justin's answer, I checked his because it was more precise and complete as it related to my problem, but your answer is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a local certificate file to access a WSDL on HTTPS:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('local_cert' => $pathToLocalCert));
```

Append this option to your current `$soap_args` and this code should work as expected. A `passphrase` option is also available if you need it for the certificate.

Comment: I already was doing so, and I removed that option because it wasn't making a difference.  The cert had no impact whatsoever on the output.

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` enabled on php.ini settings?

Comment: Yes, allow_url_fopen is enabled

Comment: alganet, BTW - I've seen conflicting answers about the 'local_cert': should it be the path to the file, or a "file_get_contents($path)" to provide a string with the contents of the cert? (Neither has worked for me but I'd appreciate your feedback anyway, for my future reference.)